# Creating a MAMP Local Copy of a Drupal 6 Website

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, themes, mamp

We're currently rebranding a client of ours and it's come the time to take the new brand to their website.
I've not much experience with Drupal other than the theming (I've themed a Drupal website in the past but not very familiar with the software's inner workings).

As this website is live, it's obviously not feasible for me to make any changes to the live environment, so I have downloaded the source files of the website to a local webserver (MAMP).
I also have a MySQL dump of the database.

I'm not sure what files need to be changed inside Drupal to allow access to the MAMP webserver. Could somebody point me in the right direction here?

How would I connect the database to the website, which files need modification?
I think the client is running Drupal 6.

**Update:**

I've installed the database and linked it up using the below line:

```
$db_url = 'mysql://root@localhost/databasename';
```

I've hidden databasename for anonymity.
As it's MAMP, the database has no password. When I load up the website I get an error that install.php is not found. It's not there because the website is already 'installed'.

I've also updated the $base_url to read:

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost:8888/foldername';
```

Comment: i got similar error now.. you have checked the answer did u resolved this problem if so please specify how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to modify one file, 'sites/default/settings.php'; you'll just need to change the database connection string in there to match your new database settings. There may be a couple of other settings in there you need to tweak depending on the set up of the site (for example the `$base_url` or `$cookie_domain`).

Other than that everything in your installation should be relatively path-ed so there shouldn't be any need to make more changes.

Comment: Thanks Clive, but no luck I'm afraid. I've updated my question with the errors I face.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same problem after couple of hours try i got solution : we have to **check the DB** (tick on list of databases in local host) [ observe this after DB list : Enabling the database statistics here might cause heavy traffic between the web server and the MySQL server. so enable only the db you want to use] this will redirect to `http://localhost:8888/foldername/install.php` successfully :D :D